# Android:Retrofit: Multiple consecutive async requests. Тoo many nested items

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
```

My steps:

1. Start async request: getCompaniesList()
2. Wait success response
3. Start another async request: getCatalogsList()
4. Wait success response
5. Do some another code

Here snippet in my activity:

```
 RestClient restClient = RestClientFactory.getRestClient();
        Call<List<Company>> companyList = restClient.getCompaniesList(filters);

        companyList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Company>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Company>> call, Response<List<Company>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    RestClient restClient = RestClientFactory.getRestClient();

                    Call<List<Catalog>> catalogList = restClient.getCatalogsList(filters);
                    catalogList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Catalog>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<Catalog>> call, Response<List<Catalog>> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                // HERE SOME NEED CODE!!!
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Catalog>> call, Throwable throwable) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Company>> call, Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
```

I think this structure is not very nice. **Тoo many nested items**. As result code is more complicated.

Question: Has any alternative to this structure?

Comment: Would recommend using `RxJava` for something like this.

Comment: We've encountered the same problem where I work. An ugly solution for better looking code would be notifying interfaces upon success and doing the work in each interface. But as @John mentioned, check out [RxJava](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/getting-started-with-rxjava-and-android) or check [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either take time to learn Rx [RXjava2](https://blog.aritraroy.in/the-missing-rxjava-2-guide-to-supercharge-your-android-development-part-1-624ef326bff4)

or you can split up your code like this

```
RestClient restClient = RestClientFactory.getRestClient();
Call<List<Company>> companyList = restClient.getCompaniesList(filters);

companyList.enqueue(getCompanyListCallback());

private Callback<List<Company>> getCompanyListCallback() {
    return new Callback<List<Company>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Company>> call, Response<List<Company>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                RestClient restClient = RestClientFactory.getRestClient();
                Call<List<Catalog>> catalogList = restClient.getCatalogsList(filters);
                catalogList.enqueue(getCatalogsListCallback());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Company>> call, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    };
}

private Callback<List<Catalog>> getCatalogsListCallback() {
  return   new Callback<List<Catalog>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Catalog>> call, Response<List<Catalog>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // HERE SOME NEED CODE!!!
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Catalog>> call, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think move inner items to separate methods (getCatalogsListCallback())  - is a good solution. As result nesting of elements always = 1. And now code is simple for read.